# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<<' (T_SL) on line 48

Tags: php, html

I have this code, but I'm getting

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<<' (T_SL) on line 48

I think the problem is from php code. but, i don't know what is it.
Can someone please explain why this error, or what my script is missing?

Thanks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script>
            function updatemenu() {
                if (document.getElementById('responsive-menu').checked == true) {
                    document.getElementById('menu').style.borderBottomRightRadius = '0';
                    document.getElementById('menu').style.borderBottomLeftRadius = '0';
                    }else{
                    document.getElementById('menu').style.borderRadius = '9px';
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
            <div id="content">
                <center><br><br>
                        <?php
                            $uid=<<<EOD 
                                ID : $_POST['user_id']
                            EOD;
                            $upw=<<<EOD 
                                PW : $_POST['user_pw']
                            EOD;
                            
                            echo $uid; 
                            echo $upw; 
                        ?>
                </center><br><br><br><br>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: **That means especially that the identifier may not be indented, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon** https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: This also would open you to XSS injections and I don't know when a password would ever be outputted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have blank space after EOD, when there should be none. Please remove it and retry. Also remove any proceeding blank space before the ending EOD;

[image]

Solution: Remove trailing space  after ALL <<<EOD and remove preceding whitespace before ALL the terminating EOD;

[image]

Comment: THX for your help.
But, when i remove blank space after EOD there's another error.
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) on line 46

Comment: Did you also remove the space before the terminiating EOD; ?

Answer (score 0):

While you could use [HEREDOC](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) it poses an issue when it comes to spaces as another answer already points out. The way that I would approach it is to use something like the following which works and is easier to read:

```html
<center><br><br>
    ID: <?php echo $_POST['user_id']; ?>
    PW: <?php echo $_POST['user_pw']; ?>
</center>
```

Reflecting the user's password back to them on the page isn't advised unless you are just getting a feel for how data moves around pages.